# Removing "\n"s when printing sentences from text file in python?

Tags: python, split, format, sentence

I am trying to print a list of sentences from a text file (one of the Project Gutenberg eBooks). When I print the file as a single string string it looks fine:

```
file = open('11.txt','r+')
alice = file.read()
print(alice[:500])
```

Output is:

```
ALICE'S ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND

Lewis Carroll

THE MILLENNIUM FULCRUM EDITION 3.0




CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole

Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the
book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or
conversations?'

So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the
hot d
```

Now, when I split it into sentences (The assignment was specifically to do this by "splitting at the periods," so it's a very simplified split), I get this:

```
>>> print(sentences[:5])
["ALICE'S ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND\n\nLewis Carroll\n\nTHE MILLENNIUM FULCRUM EDITION 3", '0\n\n\n\n\nCHAPTER I', " Down the Rabbit-Hole\n\nAlice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the\nbank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the\nbook her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in\nit, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or\nconversations?'\n\nSo she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the\nhot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure\nof making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and\npicking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran\nclose by her", "\n\nThere was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so\nVERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, 'Oh dear!\nOh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it\noccurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time\nit all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually TOOK A WATCH\nOUT OF ITS WAISTCOAT-POCKET, and looked at it, and then hurried on,\nAlice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had\nnever before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch\nto take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field\nafter it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large\nrabbit-hole under the hedge", '\n\nIn another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how\nin the world she was to get out again']
```

Where do the extra "\n" characters come from and how can I remove them?

Comment: If you split at the sentences, what does that mean exactly? Are you supposed to split on all "newline" characters or every time you see a period? If it is for the period, are you supposed to ignore the period in `CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole`?

Comment: The `\n` character is a representation of newline as an escape sequence.

Comment: @idjaw It was pretty vague. This is a pretty basic review assignment so by my assumption I am not required to get into the finer details of what constitutes a sentence so much as demonstrate that I am aware of how to use the split function - although I have looked at some of the question threads on splitting strings into sentences and am debating using a bit more "correct" code than the version I put up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace all the newlines with one space, do this:

```
import re
new_sentences = [re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', s) for s in sentences]
```

Comment: Very nice. It didn't occur to me to use a list comprehension!

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to use regex, but I would do:

```
import re
new_sentences = []
for s in sentences:
    new_sentences.append(re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n', s))
```

This should replace all instances of two or more `'\n'` with a single newline, so you still have newlines, but don't have "extra" newlines.

If you want to avoid creating a new list, and instead modify the existing one (credit to @gavriel and Andrew L.: I hadn't thought of using enumerate when I first posted my answer):

```
import re
for i, s in enumerate(sentences):
    sentences[i] = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n', s)
```

The extra newlines aren't really extra, by which I mean they are meant to be there and are visible in the text in your question: the more `'\n'` there are, the more space there is visible between the lines of text (i.e., one between the chapter heading and the first paragraph, and many between the edition and the chapter heading.

Answer (score 1):

You'll understand where the `\n` characters come from with this little example:

```
alice = """ALICE'S ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND

Lewis Carroll

THE MILLENNIUM FULCRUM EDITION 3.0




CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole

Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the
book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or
conversations?'

So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the
hot d"""

print len(alice.split("."))
print len(alice.split("\n"))
```

It all depends the way you're splitting your text, the above example will give this output:

```
3
19
```

Which means there are 3 substrings if you were to split the text using `.` or 19 substrings if you splitted using `\n` as separator. You can read more about [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

In your case you've splitted your text using `.`, so the 3 substrings will contain multiple newlines characters `\n`, to get rid of them you can either split these substrings again or just get rid of them using [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Answer (score 0):

The text uses newlines to delimit sentences as well as fullstops. You have an issue where just replacing the new line characters with an empty string will result in having words without spaces between them. Before you split `alice` by `'.'`, I would use something along the lines of @elethan's solution to replace all of the multiple new lines in `alice` with a `'.'` Then you could do `alice.split('.')` and all of the sentences separated with multiple new lines would be split appropriately along with the sentences separated with `.` initially.

Then your only issue is the decimal point in the version number.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('11.txt','r+')
file.read().split('\n')
```